# Does a bijection between to sets always permit a well defined function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Almost all definitions of bijections that I have come across define bijections as functions. I am not sure if I am wording this correctly, but does a bijection between two sets (where I mean that each element in both sets is matched with exactly one element in the other) always allow for a well defined function? In other words, if we know there is a bijection between two sets in the manner defined above, can we be assured that there *has* to be a function between the two sets?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "well-defined" function.  A bijection is itself a function, but functions are sometimes described in an oblique way so that it is not easy (or even possible) to determine $f(x)$ given $x$, but it can be shown that each $x$ has a unique $f(x)$ (and perhaps that each $y$ in the codomain has a unique $f^{-1}(y)$).  I'm guessing that such a description doesn't satisfy your notion of "well-defined".  Am I correct?

Comment: Can you maybe clarify what you mean by "well-defined function"? Sometimes it can happen that we can prove that a function exists even though we cannot construct one. (This is commonplace in applications of the axiom of choice.) Does there exist a "well-defined function" to you in this case?

Comment: I think this is exacctly what I meant..by a well defined function, I was thinking of a function that one could construct

Comment: Take A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {1,2,3,4,5}.  There are 120 possible bijections. Some will have easy to define rules.  f(n) = n+1 % 5 describes (1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,1) but others may not have any rules at all.  (1,4)(2,2)(3,1)(4,5)(5,3) for example is hard to describe.  It doesn't matter.  All bijections are, by definition, functions.  For functions from real to real we can easily imagine a bijection where every real number goes to some arbitrary real number.  That's still a function.  "well-defined" ... well, that's another issue altogether.  But it is a function.

Comment: It'd be nice to believe that any way we have of combining things could be described is a simply descriptive rule.  And I believe in a naive way we all initially assume that that must be so.  But a bit of thought shows that is not the case.  Suppose we have a nice described rule for mapping real numbers to real numbers.  Now lets say we create another mapping but *one* real number is off by *one* decimal place.  We have to be able to distinguish the difference.  For any description we can map an infinite number of maps that differ by any describable amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bijection is, by definition, a type of function. Remember that in set theory, we identify a *function* $f$ with its *graph* (that is, the set of ordered pairs $\{(a, b): f(a)=b\}$. So if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then if $S$ is a set of ordered pairs from $A\times B$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ with $(a, b)\in S$, then $S$ **is a function**. This may feel weird at first, because we tend to think of sets and functions as different types of thing; but this is how set theory works. I suspect that this is where you are getting tripped up: you may be thinking of a bijection as a set of pairs, and not realizing that that is a function already.

Another possibility is that you're thinking of "unordered bijections" (this is not an actual term). For $A, B$ disjoint sets, say that an *unordered bijection* between $A$ and $B$ is a set $S$ such that

- Every element $p$ of $S$ has exactly two elements - $p=\{a, b\}$ - and one of those elements is from $A$, and the other is from $B$.
- For each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $p\in S$ with $a\in p$.
- For each $b\in B$ there is exactly one $p\in S$ with $b\in p$.

Basically, an unordered bijection is just a bijection, but with two-element sets instead of ordered pairs. This is no longer a function; however, we can turn it into a function in a natural way: if $S$ is an unordered bijection, let $\hat{S}=\{(a, b): a\in A\mbox{ and }\{a, b\}\in S\}$. Then $\hat{S}$ is a genuine bijection from $A$ to $B$.

(Exercise: think about why unordered bijections don't make sense if $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$ . . .)

Answer (score 2):

A bijection is, by definition, a function that satisfies certain conditions. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Put differently, Is it then possible for there to be a one-to-one matching between two sets for which a function does not exist?

Comment: @KwameBrown No. I'm not even sure what that would mean.

Comment: If it's a 1-1 matching (or even a 1 to many matching) then it is, by definition a function.  I'm wondering if you are thinking a matching "without rules" can't be a function because it doesn't have a single formula.  It doesn't matter.  Any 1 to- matching whether there is a formula or not, is a function.

Answer (score 2):

bijections $\subset$ functions $\subset$ relations.

So, yes, every bijection, by definition is a function.

Relation:  a group of pairings from set $A$ to members of set $B$.  Not all elements need to be paired. And elements from either set may be in multiple pairs (or not in any pairs).

function: a relation in which *every* element of $A$ is paired with *exactly* one element of $B$.  However not every element of $B$ needs to be paired and the elements of $B$ may be in multiple pairs.  But every element of $A$ is in one and only one pair.  But two different elements of $A$ may map to the same element of $B$.

surjection: a function in which every element of $B$ is in a pair.  This is called "onto" because the function maps "onto" every element of $B$.

injection: a function in which the each element of $A$ is mapped to a *different* element of $B$.  This is *sometimes* called 1-1 because every element of $A$ is mapped 1-1 to distinct elements of $B$.  However this is ambiguous as it doesn't mean every element of $B$ has an element mapped to it.  In my opinion, I do not like to call this 1-1, and I do not.

bijection:  a function that is both a surjection and an injection.  i.e. every element of $A$ is map to exactly one distinct element of $B$ and all elements of $B$ are mapped to.  This is sometimes called "1-1 and onto" or sometimes just 1-1.  In my opinion, this should be the correct use of 1-1; I do not like to use 1-1 to describe functions that are only injective but not surjective.

*BUT*

what does "well-defined" mean?

It's possible to have a function/mapping that simply can not be described completely.  Say there is a 1-1 and onto mapping from the real numbers onto the real numbers so that every real number is mapped to a real number but the mapping is completely arbitrary and has no pattern or predictability.  The only way to describe it is to simply list all the mappings but that's impossible as the reals are uncountable.

Is that a function?  Absolutely.  No question.

Is it "well-defined"? ..... well, that depends on what the definition of "well-defined" is.  "well-defined" usually means "unambiguous" or "mathematically correct".  "Let $f(x)$ be the largest real number less than $x$" is not well-defined because there is no largest real number less than $x$".  "Let $f(x)$ = $a + b$ where $x = a*b$" is not well defined because there are many different $a,b$ so there are many different $a + b$; the function is ambiguous.

But the arbitrary mapping is neither mathematically impossible, nor ambiguous.  It is merely.... indescribable.  Does that count as not "well-defined"?  In my opinion, I'd say it is well-defined but others my, rightfully, disagree with me.

=== post script ====

In response to a comment:  I do wish to point out that the "indescribable" function which I ...er... described.... is in itself, not "defined" at all.  Probably 70% to 90% of all mathematician will disagree with me on this but I do not consider being "defined" as a requirement for being "well-defined".  I view "well-defined" to be more as a statement of "conceptually sound".  $f(a*b) = a+b$ is not conceptually sound (as $f(12) = 3+4 = 2+6$) and so is not well-defined.  Any bijective mapping between to sets *is* sound and *is* a function, whether we can define it or not.  Basically I do not consider "defining" a function to be relevant to the nature of the function and I consider the function's existence to be a form of definition-- we can *look* at it.

But, no, it is very possible to have a function that simply can not be defined in words.

tl;dr

Any bijection between sets is always a function.  It may not be able to be described but it is a function.

Comment: I wish to exercise my right to disagree. I think the word "well" is just muddying the waters. When you set out to define a function from A to B, what is your obligation? I think that you should have a rule that determines for any a in A what f(a) is. Here is an imaginary conversation: Is 7 in A? "Yes" you say. What's f(7)? I don't know." Well tell me f of somebody in A." "Sorry, I can't do that either." It's hard for me to think of something more ambiguous than your function.  If you know there's a function, pick one. Pick a card, any card. But picking is not defining.

Comment: @Airymouse But you do agree that what I described, but didn't define, would be an existant and legitimate function, don't you? The question is it "well-defined"?  Your point is valid and I fully accept your disagreement. we both agree that it isn't defined at all.  I just don't think of "well-defined" as meaning "defined well".  In my opinion, which others will disagree with, I take an existential view of math.  If a function intrinsically exists it is "good".  That we do not define it is a failure of our language and ability and not of the function... to be continued...

Comment: ... continued...  I think "well-defined" is a property of the existence of a function and not so much as our ability to describe it in language (which I consider slightly irrelevent to the function itself).  "f(a*b) = a+b" simply *can* not exist. Neither can "f(x) =y where y < x".  It's the inadequacy of the concept of the function that fails. To my mind that is property "well-defined" is meant to address. My "unpredictable" function has no inadequacy and *is* a function and *does* exist without any problem.  It's true it isn't "defined" but that is not the issue.  My opinion.  Others vary.

Comment: i"s 7 in A? "Yes" you say. What's f(7)? I don't know." Well tell me f of somebody in A." "Sorry, I can't do that either."  Actually, no.  The answer to what is f(7) would be "elephant".  Why? It just is.  That's what 7 just happens to be mapped to.  "can you tell me f of somebody?"  Yes, I can.  f(7.00001) is "ice cream". f(7.0000101001000100001....) is "Samsung cell phone".  I can keep going.  How long to you have?  "Can you name them all?" No, because I am a human being living in time.  But the *function* can name them all.  We just can't listen to it.

Comment: ... it gets rather interesting.  There is range were all real numbers between "$\pi^e$ and $127$ are all mapped to "taking a lear jet to Nova Scotia to see a total eclipse of the sun".  This function has several of those constant ranges but for the most part is simply arbitrary.  The range from $\pi^e$ to 127 is the longest such range.  It's bizarre that it also is the only one that seems to lie between describable real numbers either.

Comment: There are two issues here. You say that if a function with good properties exists, you are free to use it; I say you are free to pick one such good function and use it. From your perspective if you know that a good function exists, it is defined because although it may have other properties that you don't care about such as f(7) =17, you know it's good and that's all you need. Your second point is that had you but world enough and time you could tell me f(x) for each x in the domain. Often this is not so. Say you are proving the Fundamental Thm of Calc. with F and f as usual  Cont.

Comment: Given p in (a,b) by the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals for each x with p<x<b there is a number z(x) with p<z(x)<x such that f(z(x))(x-p) = (F(x) -F(p)).Let me assume that you and I agree from this that there is a good function, which I will call z. (Some would not agree, but that's beside the point.) Neither of us knows the values of z, even if we know the numbers a,b, and p and for the most part even if we know f explicitly. Funny you should mention a Lear Jet: my wife told me years ago there were two things I'd never be able to afford, a Lear jet and a divorce.

Comment: I am saying that the functions are functions and they exist whether we choose to define them or just obliquely refer to them as an abstract concept.  I am reserving the concept of "not well-defined" for badly stated conceptually flawed attempts at functions.  I prefer no to have it impede perfectly valid albeit indescribable functions such as my hypothetic mapping between the reals to english phrases.  The third concept of abstract unspecified functions in general is another linguistic issue.  But the basic point still holds.....

Comment: Any bijective mapping is, by definition a function. Not necessarily one that can be defined in any way other than listing the values but a function none the less. No an indescribable function may not be "well-defined" in that is isn't describable but it is a "valid and sound" function in that it is a mapping where every element of the domain is mapped to a distinct element in the codomain. So the question is what did the "OP" mean by "well-defined"?  If "well-defined" means "describable", the answer is "not nescessarily" if "well-defined" meant valid and sound, the answer is "yes, absolutely".

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In fact, a bijection is a special case of a function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realize that a function is just a mapping from one set (the domain) to another (the codomain).  It assigns an element of the codomain (the "value"), to each element of the domain (the "argument").  As Noah Schweber pointed out, it can thus be thought of as a set of ordered pairs, and a bijection is by definition a function in this sense.

This abstract definition of a function is distinct from the intuitive notion of an operation that takes an argument and somehow turns it into a result, e.g. $f(x)=x^2$, or $M(x)= x's\ \  mother$ where $x$ is a person.  Not every function (in the general sense) can be so easily described, and in some cases we might describe a function in a way that doesn't necessarily make clear what $f(x)$ is for a particular $x$, but it is still a function in the set-theoretic sense.

The question of whether an intuitively-understandable operation exists between two sets of the same cardinality is a tricky one to answer, because it depends on the intuition of the person who's asking and the cleverness of the person describing the operation.  This is one of the reasons it's helpful to think of functions simply as mappings rather than as some nebulous notion of operations.